Emergency info in NFC tag
I want to store emergency information on an NFC tag so that first responders can easily access it in case of an emergency. The tag has about 2KB of memory, and the information will be written using a dedicated app.
However, I want the reading process to be as simple and fast as possible, so it should be accessible from as many devices as possible (with an NFC reader) without requiring any additional apps to be installed.
I considered creating a web app that uses the Web NFC API, but from what I've read, it's only available on Android and not even supported by all browsers. Is that correct?
Alternatively, I thought of storing a URL on the NFC tag that links to my webpage and encoding the information in the query string of the URL. The webpage would then parse the information from the GET request and display it.
What issues might arise with this system, besides the character limit of the URL in the GET request?
Does anyone know of other alternatives?

FWIW, for iOS, at least, emergency responders are probably trained to use the native iOS “Medical ID” feature. (I don't know if Android has a similar feature.) But they might not be inclined to scan a random NFC, because it is untrusted and they have no idea where it will take them.

But in answer to your question, you would probably put a payload on the NFC that is either a URL (to some web site that has the salient information) or perhaps a VCARD that includes contact info plus any relevant notes. Then any iOS or Android device can scan the NFC natively. Re writing the relevant payload to the NFC, I wouldn't be inclined to write a web app to do that (not sure if you even can), but rather write Android and iOS apps to allow a user to write the relevant payload to the NFC. But users scanning the NFC do not need the app.

You could also encode the url as a QR code and have that embossed into a medic alert style bracelet. These have a distinctive style that first responders will be familiar with and are robust because there is no eledrronics. Eg https://www.medicalert.org.au/?gad_source=1&gbraid=0AAAAADiYj45auSbESNBhgm4Z9FKzVzCfD&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI69iYsoyliQMVfM5MAh1EOyDuEAAYASAAEgIWgPD_BwE

@Rob As for "Medical ID" or similar, it is not possible because the scenario of use of my tag is very particular and does not require that the person to be rescued has a smartphone with him and precisely because we are talking about a particular scenario, the rescuers can know of the presence of this TAG which will be highlighted visually anyway.

@Rob I will test the idea and the limits of the VCARD but you have not explained why you would not make the web app.

What is the purpose of the web app? It can’t be used for writing the NFC, AFAIK, and it is unnecessary for reading the NFC. Sure, the web app could be used to present the contents of the URL (or contents looked up on the basis of some query parameters within the URL), but that’s it; but in that case, no NFC API would be required in the web app.

By the way, when playing around with VCARD, you might want to test on both iOS and Android. Last time I did it, scanning a NFC with VCARD immediately popped up contact info in iOS, but in Android it was more clumsy, where I had to download it and then open it (though I wouldn’t be surprised if they’ve improved this; my experience on that might be out of date).

Also, if you end up bumping up against the 2k limit, you might consider type 4 or 5 NFCs that can go to 32k+.
